# Citadels: Circus (German edition, 2012): how to interpret "Cash point" ability?

Tags: citadels

To my knowledge the ability of card named "Kassenwagen" (Cash point) in the German edition of Citadels released in 2012 is translated: "Kassenwagen (Cashpoint) – Once per turn, the active player may place one gold on this card to draw two cards and keep one. You may trash this card to gain all gold on it." https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1344225/circus-expansion-action-cards-english-name

My question is how could the ability be meaningfully interpreted and should any additional house rules be added. One obstacle interpreting it is not specified when can the Cash point be discarded: can the Cash point be discarded during the same turn it was played and if so can it be discarded immediately after using the draw cards ability or does the player need to wait until his next turn.

I believe that the biggest problem with Cash point is that it is overpowered and the ability of the card should be constrained with additional house rules. During the whole game a player could use the Cash point as a safe place from characters like Thief, Emperor, Abbot or Tax Collector.

I would be grateful if anyone could suggest how to balance this action card or provide any valid arguments claiming that the card is not overpowered and should be left as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the gist of it - I would translate the card as follows:

> Each player may place one piece of gold per turn on this card while he/she is the active player. He/she may then draw 2 cards and keep 1 of them. Immediately after that, you may decide to take all the gold from this card and discard the Kassenwagen.

So it looks like to me, that anytime anyone uses the Kassenwagen, the owner may choose to take the gold immediately after their card draw resolves.  There are no rules stating that you must wait X rounds or X uses before doing so - you are limited by how often players wish to use it.  Similarly, barring any specific mention, it can be used as any other district card in the game.  I can't find a specific reference to any activation delay for any other districts with paid abilities (The Smithy coming to mind) - they are simply available for use as soon as they are built.

To me, the balance seems somewhat obvious - it's a risk/reward game.  It is a temporary haven from the Thief, Abbot, Tax Collector, and Emperor, but the longer the owner hangs onto it - the more likely he/she is likely to be targeted by the Assassin, Warlord (or even worse, the Diplomat), or by the Thief on the turn following the discard.  By holding onto the card, the player paints a very large "PAY ATTENTION TO ME" sign on him/herself.  Additionally, the other players may be wary of providing resources to another player, and may choose not to use it - limiting the effectiveness.  All in all, while it can turn into one amazing payoff, there seems to me to be an equally likely chance that the other players see what you did there and stop you from cashing in.